# Check for string inequality

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I am trying to create an `if` that sees if two Strings are 'Different' from each other.
Just like `.equals()`, but the exact opposite `:P`

it would be like:

```
 if (String a /* Is different */ String b){
     //do stuff
 }
```

Comment: The negation of `a.equals(b)` is `!a.equals(b)`.

Comment: Dang! How did I not see that? ._.'

Thanks a bunch mate! :)

Comment: Worst case, if you never heard of `!`, code `if (a.equals(b)) then {} else { do what you wanted to do }`.  Or simply `if (a.equals(b)!=true) ...`.

Comment: @HotLicks While it is true, don't suggest using `if(condition != true)` nor `if (condition==false)`, it is error prone style where one easily use `=` instead of `==`. `if (!condition)` is simple enough and safest.

Comment: @Pshemo - Good training for C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of tutorials online that show you how to compare strings.

```
String a= "a string";
 String b= "another string";

  if(!a.equals(b)){
      System.out.println("true");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = ...;
String b = ...;

if(!a.equals(b)){
//do stuff since they are not equal
}
```